# Saving Links to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a mobile website. It is HTML website.

I have design one blog page and add 100 posts. I have one page named "favourites.html".

I have added a image with each post into the blog page. I want to do, when user may click on image the link should be save to my favourite.html page as list..

I want to add these link as list with remove button.. so user can remove the links...

here is a sample image for more clarification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oZaY.jpg

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Did you tried cookie to store data?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a database table therefore with userIDs and the url of the favored blog post.

Then you just have to select the userID from table favorites and print it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 web storage to store favorites links. This will be temporary will be available until user clears cache.

If you want permanent solution you need to move it to backend.

```
var favs = [{favsurl:"someurl"},{favsurl:"someurl"},{favsurl:"someurl"}]

var favList = JSON.stringify(favs);

// Store

localStorage.setItem("favorites", favList);
```

Comment: can u please give more code.. like for click button and for the favourite,html file..... I am not good in javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use cookies. You can also use localStorage. But for blog website you need server side.

If you choose to use jquery for cookies, you need to do something like this

```
$.cookie("fav","YourValue");
```

You can download Jquery cookie plugin fro here  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

If you want it using localStorage then it will be like this

```
  localStorage.setItem("fav", "YourValue");
```

And to read you need to do something like this

```
  localStorage.getItem("fav");
```

But for a blog website, you got to have backend development